# PPT VBA, saving as PDF all opened ppts

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have multiple presentations open and want to save those As PDF. I have this code:

```
For Each prs In Presentations
    With prs.Windows(1)
        If Not .Active Then
            .Activate
        End If
    End With
    
    ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat "d:\\temp\\" & prs.Name & "-color.pdf", _
        ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentScreen, msoCTrue, ppPrintHandoutVerticalFirst, _
        ppPrintOutputSlides, msoFalse, , , , False, False, False, False, False

 Next prs
```

But it save as PDF only the window that I started with. It doesn't save the PDF for each presentation though PPT active window changes.

I tried another method that used to work for other methods:
For Each prs In Presentations

```
prs.ExportAsFixedFormat "d:\\temp\\" & prs.Name & "-color.pdf", _
    ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentScreen, msoCTrue, ppPrintHandoutVerticalFirst, _
    ppPrintOutputSlides, msoFalse, , , , False, False, False, False, False
```

Next prs
But this gives an error from macro editor "**type-mismatch**" so can't run this.

I couldn't figure out how to solve this issue. Can you please suggest what I can do to perform this task?

Thanks for help

Vikas

Comment: When I said it only saves the windows I started with, I meant it keeps saving the same active presentation with different names.

Answer (score 0):

Let's fix the logic first. And I've removed the excess backslashes from the ExportAsFixedFormat command; if they must be there for some reason, put 'em back.
Give it a try this way; if the export still throws wobblies, let us know.

```
For Each prs In Presentations
    
    prs.ExportAsFixedFormat "d:\temp\" & prs.Name & "-color.pdf", _
        ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentScreen, msoCTrue, ppPrintHandoutVerticalFirst, _
        ppPrintOutputSlides, msoFalse, , , , False, False, False, False, False

 Next prs
```

Comment: I took the code above, but it gave the error that I mentioned before. That is " Runtime error '13'. Type mismatch"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found the problem. Powerpoint had some files in memory, so when I was running loop on Presentations, it was getting some PDF file from presentation (which I opened couple days ago mistakenly in PPT). They were still in PPT's Presentations variable. So when it was calling prs.ExportAsFixedFormat the method didn't exist on that object so it was failing with 'method not found error'.
I added code to make sure the presentation I am getting is actually a PPT (code below).

AFter that when I ran the code it was still giving 'type mismatch' error. So I added code to Set object as Presentation object, then it worked nicely.
This was the edited code I am using now:

```
Dim p As Presentation
For Each prs In Presentations
    Set p = prs
    If InStr(p.Name, "ppt") <> 0 Then
        p.ExportAsFixedFormat "d:\temp\" & p.Name & "-color.pdf", _
            ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentScreen, msoCTrue, ppPrintHandoutVerticalFirst, _
            ppPrintOutputSlides, msoFalse, , , , False, False, False, False, False
    End If
 Next prs
```

Thanks for your help
Vikas